# How do I measure the number of commits before a push from a Git repository?

Tags: git, push, commit, metrics, github-api

I'm  developing a tool for gathering metrics on Git repositories. I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the number of commits within a push, such that I could say "for repository *x*, an average of *y* commits are made before a push". In this instance, merge commits can be ignored. I attempted this using libgit2 with no success, as I don't believe Git itself stores this information in its object database.

Though it seems GitHub can infer when a push has been made, so it must be possible. GitHub shows in the home page a list of recent commits by committer (for organizations you're a member of and people you're following), and displays the commits as squished together when they were pushed together.

How can I get this information, using either the GitHub API or some other library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determine the number of commits in a given push you need to get the stream of [PushEvents](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) for a repository.

You'll want to poll the [repository events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-repository-events) endopint and filter through the response for `PushEvents`. In the payload for a `PushEvent` is a `size` attribute. That should tell you how many commits were pushed in that event. If that has been removed (without being documented as removed) then you should be able to determine the length of `commits` attribute since it is a collection of objects that represent each commit. If you were doing this in JavaScript, you could do `payload.commits.length` or `len(payload['commits'])` in Python for example.

Suggestions for a specific library are out of scope for StackOverflow questions though so I will not answer that for you.